# Changes not reflecting on angular app after deployment

Tags: angular, docker

I have an angular application I have hosted the source code in a centos server. I have an issue whenever I update my code locally and push then it to the server I don't see any changes reflected when I view the app in my browser. I tried running the following commands to build the dist file and run the server again but there are no changes:

`docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t e-app:v1 .`

`docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 e-app:v1`

I believe this is happening because the built dist (built by executing the Dockerfile) is still the same it hasn't changed.

**Dockerfile**

```
# stage 1 
FROM node:latest as node 

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .


RUN npm i -f

RUN npm audit fix

# RUN npm install 

RUN npm run build --prod 

# stage 2 
FROM nginx:alpine 
COPY --from=node /app/dist/e-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: have you clear browser cookies or reload the angular page?

Comment: I got this error: `Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 19: COPY requires at least two arguments, but only one was provided. Destination could not be determined.` Are you sure that your Dockerfile is correct?

Comment: @Abhishek yes I have but there no changes

Comment: I have corrected line 19

Comment: Is it behind Cloudflare or any proxy services? If not, can you try it in incognito?

Comment: @AravindSaiVellappat   I have just tried to open the link in Incognito mode everything is fine now I can see the changes.

Comment: @PhilipMutua Glad that it worked. :)

Comment: @PhilipMutua at some point in the future, try add an answer and accept it - just so the question isn't left unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below command to make application build

> ng --prod  build --output-hashing=all